# When I loop through a MySQL array, JavaScript works on the first echoed data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, ajax

I am having trouble getting a desired result on my code. When I loop through an array of data, JavaScript works only on the first echoed data.

**Code Snippet:**

```
     <?php

                    $ids = array();


                    array_push($ids, getRandom($id));
                    array_push($ids, getRandom($id));
                    array_push($ids, getRandom($id));

                    $ids = array_unique($ids);
                    if (count($ids) > 0) {
                    foreach($ids as $value => $val) {

                        //data saved in variables


                        <li>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <div class="avatar">
                                       <!--avartar -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                   <!-- data -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
                                    <button id = "button1" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning btn-icon"><i class="fa  fa-plus"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
 <script>
                 $("#button1").on("click",function() {
                     alert("hey");
                 });
</script>
```

Comment: [___There must not be multiple `elements` in a `document` that have the same `id` value.___](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the JavaScript function to work for any button click:

```
$("button").on("click",function() {
    alert("hey");
});
```

And it's also worth noting you shouldn't use the same ID for more than one element:

```
<button id = "button_<?= $val ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning btn-icon"><i class="fa  fa-plus"></i></button>
```

This will create a unique ID for each button element

Answer (score 1):

id's should be unique, try using a class instead.

Most browsers when selecting the ID in javascript respect the standard and respond you with only the first element.

Try removing the ID

```
<div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
  <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning btn-icon"><i class="fa  fa-plus"></i></button>
</div>
```

and then:

```
$(".btn").on("click",function() {
   alert("hey");
});
```

Comment: You should have explain how to change the value in the id instead of showing the JavaScript. Your answer doesn't explain enough.